# Access multi-level array in php to get middle keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mapreduce, associative-array

I have a array structure as shown below.

```
$arr = [ "level1" =>
         ["level2" =>
          ["level3" =>
           [ "key1" => "value1",
             "key2" => "value2",
               ]
              ]
             ],
         [ "level2-A" =>
           ["level3-A" =>
            [  "key1" => "value1-A",
               "key2" => "value2-A",
                ]
               ]
             ],
         "level2-B" => "value",
         "level2-c" => "value",

    ];
```

Expected output is as below :

```
[ "level3" => "value2",
  "level3-A" => "value2-A",
  "level2-B" => "value",
];
```

I have tried using **array_map_reduce**, but I could fetch only till level2.

Comment: Can you please share the actual code you tried and explain the logic behind the desired result?

Comment: It would also help if you made sense of your example array. 7 brackets are open, 5 are closed.

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: it is always 3rd level key, with once exception, which I can handle separately.

Comment: This array structure doesn't make sense to me. `$arr` is a mix of associative and indexed elements. Should there be a `level2` key for the array that begins with `level2-A`?

Comment: Where does `level3 => value2` come from in the result? Is it the last value in the array?

Comment: Use 3 nested loops.

Comment: Why no `level2-c => value` in the result? Shouldn't it be added by the same logic as `level2-B => value`?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. Check whether each level is an array before trying to loop through it.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key1 => $level1) {
    if (is_array($level1)) {
        foreach ($level1 as $key2 => $level2) {
            if (is_array($level2)) {
                foreach ($level2 as $key3 => $level3) {
                    foreach ($level3 as $value) {
                        // loop to the end of the array
                    }
                    $result[$key3] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $result[$key1] = $level1;
    }
}
```

The result of this is

```
Array
(
    [level3] => value2
    [level3-A] => value2-A
    [level2-B] => value
    [level2-c] => value
)
```

I don't know the logic that should prevent adding `level2-c` to the result.